# can sftp and ssh share same default port?

Tags: ssh, rsync, sftp

I have ssh already setup to use 22 port and now I enabled sftp

i.e.  disabled so I enabled and started service

```
systemctl enable sshd
systemctl start sshd
```

as well on same port but now if I try to rsync from my mac to my ubuntu server I get error on my mac

> rsync -arvz --progress /Users/username/ceres_pi/cron.sh
>   rock64@rock64:/home/ protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
>   (see the rsync man page for an explanation)

**Update**

```
dietpi@DietPi:~$ ssh rock64@192.168.1.110
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.110 (192.168.1.110)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:yCe/kd4ghvvjhkgi3ToFj6vUqjtBqM2Hc+xqtM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.110' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
rock64@192.168.1.110's password: 
packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.1.110 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Comment: "enabled sftp" how, exactly? normally it would be enabled by default using the openssh-server's internal `sftp-server` subsystem. Did you install a standalone sftp implementation of some kind instead?

Comment: I meant sshd was disabled so I enabled and started service

Comment: i tried on another rasbian vm still got the same error

Comment: AFAIK the most likely cause of that error is that your remote shell initialization is writing stuff it shouldn't - see for example [Rsync seems incompatible with .bashrc (causes “is your shell clean?”)](https://serverfault.com/a/304126) - nothing to do with whether sftp is enabled or not

Comment: I rebooted my remote ubuntu server i cant even ssh now

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe exactly what you did - *"sshd was disabled so I enabled and started service"* and *"setup to use 22 port and now I enabled sftp as well on same port"* are not the same thing, at all

Comment: now after reboot I get this error trying too access from a vm

Comment: @steeldriver updated

Answer (score 0):

`Broken pipe` occurs when your SSH connection was cut off due to a long period of inactivity. To prevent it from happening, do the following.

On the server,(in your case, 192.168.1.110) add the two lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

Save the file and restart the `sshd` using

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: following a online guide I set this command blindly `ForceCommand internal-sftp` what does it do ?
Also is it advisable to have `ChrootDirectory /mnt/cifs/Downloads` remote mount ?

Comment: I followed your steps and I now get message `This service allows sftp connections only.
Connection to rock64 closed.` if I try to ssh remotely.

Comment: and if I changed the port to 2222 in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I get connection refused

Comment: I have sftp working but cannot ssh now

Comment: Edit the `sshd_config` file and add these lines.
        `PubkeyAuthentication yes`
        `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`(each on seperate line). Add your public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

    Then, start the ssh server with port 22/TCP open `/etc/init.d/sshd start`
     `iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 22`

Finally, test  `sftp <user>@<host>`

Comment: Using a same port for multiple services is not a good idea. That is the reason why ports exist.